# Gather a slice given an idex array

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an input tensor `params` of size `(BxHxWx200)` and an index array `idx` of size `(Bx1000x2)`. `idx` holds 1000 different locations of `param` tensor, i.e. the last axis (the one of size 2) is `HxW` location which corresponds to the `params` input tensor. I want to get the slice of `params` of size `(Bx1000x200)` that corresponds to the locations in `idx`.

In NumPy, it would be as simple as `params[idx]`. I am not sure how to do it in TensorFlow.

If I try `output = tf.gather_nd(params, idx)` I am getting a tensor of size `(Bx1000xWx200)`. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another index in the last dimension of `idx` to index the first axis of `params`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data (can be dynamic shapes)
B, H, W = 10, 20, 30
params = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [B, H, W, 200])
idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [B, 1000, 2])
# Dimensions of idx
idx_s = tf.shape(idx, out_type=idx.dtype)
# Index for first dimension of params
r = tf.range(idx_s[0])
# Tile r to match the shape of idx
idx_b = tf.tile(r[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], (1, idx_s[1], 1))
# Make the complete index
idx_full = tf.concat([idx_b, idx], axis=-1)
# Gather the result
out = tf.gather_nd(params, idx_full)
print(out.shape)
# (10, 1000, 200)
```